# Get Clock In and clock out time from multiple clock in or multiple clock out in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in web application to manage staff with clock in/out time and mapping with planned shift.

Note LogType 1  means clock In and 2 is clock Out.

I have login table structure as below

```
UserId       LogDateTime             LogType

 5005    2019-05-20 21:35:48.490        1
 5005    2019-05-20 22:25:00.000        1
 5005    2019-05-21 06:48:00.000        2
 5005    2019-05-21 07:01:15.383        2

 5006    2019-05-20 21:25:25.470        1
 5006    2019-05-20 23:48:29.568        2
 5006    2019-05-21 00:07:05.056        1
 5006    2019-05-21 07:25:35.853        2

 5007   2019-05-20 23:33:35.017         1
 5007   2019-05-21 00:18:56.087         2
 5007   2019-05-21 09:01:23.577         2
```

I want to get clock In and Clock out in below format and use it for mapping with planned shift

```
UserId      Date            ClockIn                    ClockOut
5005      2019-05-20     2019-05-20 21:35:48.490     2019-05-21 07:01:15.383
5006      2019-05-20     2019-05-20 21:25:25.470     2019-05-21 07:25:35.853
5007      2019-05-21     2019-05-20 23:33:35.017     2019-05-21 09:01:23.577
```

Any one can share the query for that.

Comment: you can have multiple clock-in without clock-out ? And why `5006` not reported under 2 different date ? Please update the question with the logic

Comment: Can you please explain the `Date` column logic little more. How it is `2019-05-20` for UserId `5005` and `2019-05-21` for UserId `5007` ?

Comment: Please either provide more details in your question, review the answer posted and post comments to it if needed, or delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, `<myTable>` needs to be replaced with the actual name of the table:

```
SELECT 
    UserId,
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), LogDateTime, 126) AS Date,
    LogDateTime AS ClockIn,
    -- this sub query will by using WHERE clause, ORDER BY, TOP 1
    -- get the closest CheckOut time for the same user
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 LogDateTime 
        FROM <myTable> AS t2 
        WHERE t2.UserId = t1.UserId 
              AND t2.LogDateTime > t1.LogDateTime
              AND LogType = 2
        ORDER BY LogDateTime ASC
    )  AS ClockOut
FROM <myTable> AS t1 
WHERE LogType = 1
    -- this sub query is to limit the result to only the latest CheckIn times
    AND t1.LogDateTime IN
    (
        SELECT MAX(t3.LogDateTime)
        FROM <myTable> AS t3
        WHERE t3.UserId = t1.UserId
          AND LogType = 1
    )
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: The OP needs selecting Date column too, and we need more explanation (as  Arulkumar's comment ) as the date is `Min()` with  `5005` and `Max()` with `5007` !

Comment: Well I've wrote an answer that I think the user *might want*. The query is quite complex (it needs to be complex, but it could be written in other ways). Also the query might not have great performance, but it should be a start

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the logic behind `Date` column is considering the date while the user assigned both checkin and out, if the user assigned checkin only or checkout only the record will be ignored (In practical life maybe it happens for User forgetting)

Anyways for achieving that you should use `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `Group By` and `Having` as next

**I think there is a nicer code for mine, but at least mine is achieving the need**

**Demo**:-

```
Create table #MyTempTable (UserId int , LogDateTime Datetime,LogType int)

Insert into #MyTempTable values (5005,'2019-05-20 21:35:48.490',1)
Insert into #MyTempTable values (5005,'2019-05-20 22:25:00.000',1)
Insert into #MyTempTable values (5005,'2019-05-21 06:48:00.000',2)
Insert into #MyTempTable values (5005,'2019-05-21 07:01:15.383',2)
Insert into #MyTempTable values (5006,'2019-05-20 21:25:25.470',1)
Insert into #MyTempTable values (5006,'2019-05-20 23:48:29.568',2)
Insert into #MyTempTable values (5006,'2019-05-21 00:07:05.056',1)
Insert into #MyTempTable values (5006,'2019-05-21 07:25:35.853',2)
Insert into #MyTempTable values (5007,'2019-05-20 23:33:35.017',1)
Insert into #MyTempTable values (5007,'2019-05-21 00:18:56.087', 2)
Insert into #MyTempTable values (5007,'2019-05-21 09:01:23.577',2)

select UserId,min(Date) Date ,min(ClockIn) ClockIn ,Max(ClockOut) ClockOut 
from (
    select UserId, Min(convert(date,LogDateTime)) Date, 
    Min(LogDateTime) ClockIn , Max(LogDateTime) ClockOut,LogType
    from #MyTempTable
    Group by UserId,LogType
    having count(convert(date,LogDateTime)) > 1
    )t
Group by UserId

Drop table #MyTempTable
```

**Result**:-

```
UserId  Date        ClockIn                 ClockOut
5005    2019-05-20  2019-05-20 21:35:48.490 2019-05-21 07:01:15.383
5006    2019-05-20  2019-05-20 21:25:25.470 2019-05-21 07:25:35.853
5007    2019-05-21  2019-05-21 00:18:56.087 2019-05-21 09:01:23.577
```

Comment: Your solution does not seems to be working for some reasons . First of all, you didn't give any attention to the date of the `ClockIn` and `ClockOut`, so the result will be with different date in the `ClockIn` and the `ClockOut` and this is is not acceptable

Comment: Calm a down bro, _this is is not acceptable_ from who?! The data demo that I used is not dummy data it is the input from OP, and the result that I recached is the same that OP looking for due to his\her question. Finally I wrote an answer that I think it helps.

Comment: Maybe is it helpful for him , but not helped for the others readers ( who searched for a solution ) .