# Get one Clock In and one clock out time from a record employee table

Tags: sql, sql-server, time-and-attendance

In the attendance system, many users when uses the attendance device can commit mistakes when they imprint two times or more ( for the `clockIn` ) and two time or more ( for the `clockOut`) . So what I have is a table that get all records ( `ClockIn` and `ClockOut` ) for all users " duplicated " .

I'm searching for a method to get only the `max` of the `clockout` and the `min` of the `clockIn`.

I saw a solution for this question on stackoverflow :

[Get Clock In and clock out time from multiple clock in or multiple clock out in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56269439/get-clock-in-and-clock-out-time-from-multiple-clock-in-or-multiple-clock-out-in)

I have tested it , it gives the result expected but not in all case.

**1/ Table schema and select query that I have created:**

In my case, I have a table that contains employee_records and I would like to get only one `ClockIn` and only `ClockOut` in the same date .

```
employeerecordId        AddAt           logtype
```

What I need exactly is getting all clockIn and clockOut between two dates ( duration ) ( only one clock and one clockOut for the same day)

how can I do that?

```
select t.employeeId,MIN(cast(clockIn as time(7))) ClockIn, max(cast(ClockOut as time(7))) clockout 
from (select r.employeeId, MIN(cast(r.AddAt as time(7))) clockIn,MAX(cast(r.AddAt as time(7))) clockout , logtype
from emplyee_recoards r 
group by r.employeeId,logtype
)t 
where CAST(a as date) between @datefrom and @dateto 
group by employeeId
```

**2/ Sample table data to test the solution proposed
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56269439/get-clock-in-and-clock-out-time-from-multiple-clock-in-or-multiple-clock-out-in)**

Create the table and insert data on it:

```
Create table #MyTempTable (employeeId int , addat Datetime,LogType int)
    Insert into #MyTempTable values (5005,'2019-05-20 21:35:48.490',1)
    Insert into #MyTempTable values (5005,'2019-05-20 22:25:00.000',1)
    Insert into #MyTempTable values (5005,'2019-05-20 06:48:00.000',0)
    Insert into #MyTempTable values (5005,'2019-05-20 07:01:15.383',0)
    Insert into #MyTempTable values (5005,'2019-05-25 08:01:15.383',0)
    Insert into #MyTempTable values (5005,'2019-05-25 09:01:15.383',0)
    Insert into #MyTempTable values (5005,'2019-05-25 22:01:15.383',1)
    Insert into #MyTempTable values (5005,'2019-05-25 20:01:15.383',1)
    
    Insert into #MyTempTable values (5006,'2019-05-20 21:25:25.470',1)
    Insert into #MyTempTable values (5006,'2019-05-20 23:48:29.568',1)
    Insert into #MyTempTable values (5006,'2019-05-20 08:48:29.568',0)
    Insert into #MyTempTable values (5006,'2019-05-20 09:38:29.568',0)
    Insert into #MyTempTable values (5005,'2019-05-25 08:01:15.383',0)
    Insert into #MyTempTable values (5005,'2019-05-25 09:01:15.383',0)
    Insert into #MyTempTable values (5005,'2019-05-25 22:01:15.383',1)
    Insert into #MyTempTable values (5005,'2019-05-25 20:01:15.383',1)



select employeeId,min(Date) Date ,min(ClockIn) ClockIn ,Max(ClockOut) ClockOut 
from (
    select employeeId, Min(convert(date,addat)) Date, 
    Min(addat) ClockIn , Max(addat) ClockOut,LogType
    from #MyTempTable
    Group by employeeId,LogType
    having count(convert(date,addat)) > 1
    )t
Group by employeeId

Drop table #MyTempTable
```

**will return:**

[image]

The expected result:

```
EmployeeId      AddAt            ClockIn                    ClockOut
5005               2019-05-20     2019-05-20 06:48:00.000     2019-05-20 22:25:00.000
5005               2019-05-25     2019-05-25 08:01:15.383     2019-05-25 22:01:15.383
5006               2019-05-20     2019-05-20 08:48:29.568     2019-05-20 23:48:29.568
5006               2019-05-25     2019-05-25 08:01:15.383     2019-05-25 22:01:15.383
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results *in the question* and perhaps also in a db/sql fiddle.  Please clearly explain the logic that *you* want to implement for "duplicated" rows.

Comment: Stop cramming your code together - as you've been told previously. Format it so that it is easy read by humans, which will encourage others to look at your code and your issue.

Comment: So what happens if someone clocks on the same day any of these combinations 1. in, in, out 2. in, out, out 3. in, out, in 4. in, out, in, out 5. out, in 6. out, in, out 7.out, in, out, in, what result would you like for these?

Comment: @SMor , I have update my question.

Comment: @Charlieface , in the same day will take the `Max(ClockOut)` and the `Min(ClockIn)`, this is mentioned on my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to group by the employee and date, then use conditional aggregation to split out the clock-ins and -outs.

```sql
select
    employeeId,
    convert(date,addat) Date, 
    Min(CASE WHEN LogType = 0 THEN addat END) ClockIn,
    Max(CASE WHEN LogType = 1 THEN addat END) ClockOut
from #MyTempTable
Group by employeeId, convert(date,addat)
```